# C++ Assigning words from file input to strings or ints

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, getline

I need to open a file in this format

```
Firstname Lastname 1 2 3 4 5

Firstname Lastname 2 3 4 5 6
```

I need to assign the first name of a line to a member array of structs and last name of the line to another member of the struct and each number of the line to a array of scores in the struct and each new line goes to the next index of the struct array, doing the same thing (Sorry if I worded that badly).

I'm not too worried about the score assignment I have an idea of how to do that but right now I'm trying to use getline to assign each word at a time to the strings inside the structs but when I run the code, it skips the first line and inputs the first and last name of the second line and I can't figure out how to make it start with the first line.

Here is my code

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("Scores.txt");
if (!(fin.is_open()))
    cout << "Failed to open file.\n";

if (stuCount < 10)
{
    for (int n = 0; !fin.eof();)
    {
        for (string line[10]; getline(fin, line[n]); n++)
        {
            fin >> students[stuCount].fname >> students[stuCount].lname;
            stuCount++;
            cout << line[n] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that both getline and the (>>) operator are advancing the position of the read buffer in the stream. You need to buffer your call to getline.

An idea for changing your code up would be this:

```
ifstream fin("Scores.txt", ifstream::in);
if (!fin.is_open()) {
cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
    return -1;
}

if (stuCount < 10)
{
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        string line;
        getline(fin, line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> students[stuCount].fname >> students[stuCount].lname;
        cout << line << endl;
        stuCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately we haven't gone over string streams in class yet so I can't use it. Do you know of any other way?

Comment: @DatNguyen Then you are on the right track with your original question, you will just need to fix your loops. Change the for loops to be like the while loop I posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still skips the first line when I use that loop.